# An inmate is teleported back and forth for a mathematical formula

Tags: story-identification

In the 90s I saw an episode of a sci-fi series. The episode is about an inmate that travels (is made to travel) to another world/dimension several times. It is something of an experiment.

Each time he gets back with a part of a mathematical formula and transforms more and more into a blue alien each time.

I thought this might be an episode of The Outer Limits, but I can't find any that match.

Comment: I don't know, but this sounds cool!